# The example of the number of moduli is not equal to dim $H^1(M, \Theta)$, where $M$ is surface.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

In the following paper, the author showed that the number of moduli is not equal to the tangent space of deformations dim$H^1(M_t,\Theta_t)$. In which the author said *Full proofs will appear elsewhere*.

I cannot find where he (Arnold Samuel Kas) gives the proof? Is there some paper?

*On Obstructions to Deformations of Complex Analytic Surfaces
Arnold Kas
Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences of the United States of America
Vol. 58, No. 2 (Aug. 15, 1967), pp. 402-404*

Comment: You might want to look at Vakil's paper on Murphy's Law. It gives many more examples of such varieties.

Comment: I found the page:(https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411469), thank you.